# Merge all synonyms for [dagger-hilt]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[Dagger Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/) was presented recently. It simplifies Dagger-related infrastructure for Android apps.

People created several tags related to it:

- [dagger-hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger-hilt) - 47 questions
- [hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilt) - 33 questions
- [android-hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-hilt) - 20 questions
- [hilt-dagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilt-dagger) - 18 questions
- [android-jetpack-hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-hilt) - 12 questions

I think all these should be synonyms for [dagger-hilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger-hilt), since this is the most suitable name.

Comment: Is this a [dagger-hilt] I see before me?

Comment: I can see an argument for not merging [android-jetpack-hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack), especially now that it's being used correctly, but the rest are definitely synonyms.

Comment: @Nitrodon Can you please elaborate on this? AFAIK, Dagger Hilt was developed internally and then it was released as alpha in Jetpack library collection (and the development process is running there). So I think it means the same thing currently.

Comment: Since I have enough reputation in `dagger-hilt`, I made all the other tags synonyms of it (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dagger-hilt/synonyms). Now they just need to be upvoted, if no moderator wants to take care of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I had enough reputation in `dagger-hilt` I suggested the mentioned synonyms.

After that, I found and contacted (through twitter & StackOverflow) people who had enough reputation to upvote those synonyms. It was a bit tough because we needed 4 votes, and there are only 5 people who could upvote this...

All the hard work finally paid off, and we have those synonyms approved!

Comment: Nice dig against the lazy moderators there. You do realize how many retagging requests are posted on Meta *per day*, right? And the limited number of mods there are here? And the zillions of other jobs that mods have beyond this? Sorry we didn't get to this one quickly enough to suit you. The backlog is *years* long, not weeks. I agree that the tag synonym system is broken; that is something I've been fighting to fix [for almost 10 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211). It isn't going to happen, so the mods try to do their best. I've merged these tags now and marked this as complete.

Comment: @CodyGray Lol man. Why don't you chill down a bit. Since when I'm not allowed to give my opinion on mods not taking care of this? I do feel like this should be looked at before 

Comment: AFAIK, moderators shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: I agree @Braiam, but currently the process is as is. The system of synonyms is just broken and it's virtually impossible for regular users to push tag synonyms.

Comment: I was a bit offended by your "side note". I did *not* say that you aren't allowed to give your opinion. Similarly, I am allowed to give mine.

Comment: @BartekLipinski Mods have plenty of work, just take a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399613/12708583) to see what I mean.

Comment: The issue isn't mods, the issue is with the top users of the tag. If you look at the [latest 30 synonym requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request?tab=newest&pagesize=30), you'll see that the ones which don't have a [status-] tag are the ones where there are opposing views. This, for example had a comment against merging a given tag. There were no comments apart from the OP when I reviewed this on Aug 5th. If the top users in the tag were much more active leaving comments/answers either for or against tag requests, then it would make it easier for mods to handle.

Comment: @CodyGray You're more than welcome to give me your opinion, but you shouldn't be aggressive. I would love to read your point of view regarding the state of tag-synonym system, but you got all "raged-up" on me. It just feels sad at this point. I could've gotten offended by your opinion as well, but I haven't.

Comment: @BartekLipinski Your initial comments on this come across as passive aggressive at best. Moderators are volunteers. We're not on the site 24/7. Also we're not all experts in all technologies so the moderators who saw this might not have felt that they could complete the merge without input from other people.

Comment: @ChrisF so I guess no one will ever admit or address openly aggressive message from CodyGray ? You'll just redirect everything that is being said here to me? Cool, cool. I guess this conversation is pointless. Thanks for merging the tag CodyGray. Cheers guys!