# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow’s [twelfth moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Makyen] [image: Machavity]

They’ll be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5154305393819648/0).

Comment: Congratulations, Makyen and Machavity!

Comment: Congrats to both! You've both chosen to pick up your shovels during an extremely trying time. Now, go do your best!

Comment: OK, now for my next question: When is the third moderator going to be picked? ;-)

Comment: Congrats to the both of you!

Comment: Ah yes, finally the Team Fortress 2 Engineer we deserve! But seriously, congrats to both of you!

Comment: Congrats from me, too. Glad to have you on board!

Comment: I see I placed my bets on winning combination :) Congrats!

Comment: Congrats Makyen and Machavity! 

I know you are both hard workers and look forward to a cleaner site :)

Comment: Congrats you two would have both had my vote if my rep was higher.

Comment: Basically, the SOCVR guys slowly but surely transitioning into mods.

Comment: SOCVR could always use additional people :eyes:

Comment: @cs95 for as many moderators as have left over the last year, and based on the voting results IMO they should appoint both the #3 and #4 candidates to moderator status.

Comment: Congratulations. And the number of voters is impressive too. Maybe the size of the candidates field was a bit smaller this time. SO has been lucky that both Ms were running again.

Comment: Congratulations, and - in the immortal words of a great former moderator - "Break's over, back on your heads!"

Comment: Congrats to you both, though I do not envy the task you have volunteered for here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg we should probably give the diamond directly to the room --> SOCVR ♦

Comment: Great Job! Happy to see the results. I feel you two will be great mods!

Comment: Congratulations and good luck you two...

Comment: Congo Both of you, Happy to see a candidate selected from my vote contribution :-)

Comment: Congratulations! You were both among my choices. Wishing you good luck and wisdom, you've got a tough job ahead of you!

Comment: Congratulations and good luck for this job!

Comment: Many thanks for all the community support. I will do all I can to remain worthy of this diamond

Comment: Just curious, I was looking over the [ballots](https://www.opavote.com/ballots/5154305393819648/0?p=4) and saw that of the 7 single-vote ballots, Yvette's had the most weight (I assume that "weight" in this context means number of ballots cast like that) and of the triple-vote ballots, Yvette(1)-Makyen(2)-Machavity(3) also had the most weight. Of course that doesn't mean much alone since there were 250 other ballots, but I'd be interested to see how the votes turned out with her counted. I tried making OpaVote recount the data for me, but they wanted $30 to do it, and I'm not $30 curious ;)

Comment: @DavyM You should be able to download the raw data from [the election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12), open it in OpenSTV, and run it yourself. Note that the Unicode characters in CrazyPython's name will cause the file to appear as corrupted. You'll need to edit that with a hex editor to replace it with ASCII. There's no problem doing that, as there's no checksumming or other protection on the file. Then, you can run the vote counting using whatever parameters you like. Note, ofc, that Yvette withdrew early, so many people changed their vote, so you can't get an accurate estimate.

Comment: @CodyGray Since we've now deleted Yvette's account, I'm not actually sure the data in the file will work. When you click to download that information, it's calculated on the fly and when a candidate is removed, it can no longer be created.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. I'm not interested in an accurate estimate of what the vote would have been if she didn't drop out, I'm interested in the results as they stand, so that will work for me. Catija, in the case of the data file, I can download (and have downloaded now to go try Cody's suggestion) the one used for the final tallies on OpaVote, which isn't affected by account deletion since that's not hosted here.

Comment: Congrats Makyen and Machavity. We forsee a much cleaner site some months down the line.

Comment: Congratulation Makyen  and @Machavity I do hope that you will work truly for the betterment of the community ...

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your votes and support. I'll do my best to wield the diamond in service of our community.

Comment: Congratulations guys, keep up the good work. Whether you know it or not, you are providing a great support to the community. Bravo

Comment: Congratulations Makyen and Machavity! I'm sure SO will have not just cleaner Q&A, but also more community supports :)

Comment: Congratulations Makyen and Machavity , now you can sleep for 4 hours per day :D :D high paid jobs are waiting for you :P :P

Answer (score 208):

Congratulations to the new moderators!

I’d post a picture of brooms for sweeping but I lost it under the pile of flags....

Comment: Now THAT was funny.

Comment: And you lost that under the sock puppets :)

Comment: Correction-- SOck puppets :)

Answer (score 164):

Don't worry - we saved some for you.

[image]

Welcome to the fray.

Update: they have made progress.

[image]

Comment: Yow! You really were needing new moderators, weren't you!

Comment: Are those... custom flags?

Comment: Everything, @cs95. 734 'other' flags right now.

Comment: @cs95 I cleared the Meta flags out. 2 down...

Comment: @Machavity gotta start somewhere! Keep it up, all the best. The diamond looks good on you.

Comment: @Andrew: That's pretty normal. The flag count is something of a flow-rate problem: if you check next week, you'll still see a thousand flags, but they're likely a completely different thousand. The average flag is handled in about six hours.

Comment: Wow... and I get stressed when I see the number reaching 40 in the Spanish site :O

Comment: Like the US deficit, the number has gotten so large that it's just an abstract concept now, hardly something that anyone worries about or ever expects to pay. We live because of the promise of infinity created by the flag queue. See also: [*Global Debt and Parallel Universe*, by Jean Baudrillard](https://facultyweb.wcjc.edu/users/jonl/documents/gdpu.pdf) :-)

Comment: The update is even more mind-boggling than the original screenshot. Respect!

Answer (score 128):

Congratulations to both Makyen and Machavity!

You were, as I'm sure everyone suspected, my top two choices for moderator, certainly among the candidates, but perhaps even if I had my pick of users. You are both supremely qualified, and I have full trust in your judgment and abilities not only to perform the day-to-day slog of moderation, but also to represent the community with aplomb.

As Makoto points out, you both have the stamina and "stick-to-it-iveness" to keep going, even when the going gets hard, because you know it needs to be done and you're here for the right reasons.

We are all incredibly lucky to have you, and we truly appreciate your stepping up to do a largely thankless job.

Now, that's enough enough celebrating… Our garbage piles are overflowing; get to raking!

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks like a perfectly good basketball!

Comment: @Undo it would take a veteran moderator to find the diamond in the rough instead of just deleting all of it.  :D

Comment: @Undo What you can't see is that the other side of the basketball has a sockpuppet in it.

Comment: Good choice of... choices. I made the same picks for my top two. After that, I think I had Dharman.

Comment: @Dan is that a shot at Dharman?  S.S.Anne, that was my vote card as well.

Comment: I had, at one early point, Dharman as my second place over Machavity. I later thought better of it and modified my ballot. Machavity has been around here a *long* time, giving an unbelievable amount of time, patience, and good will to these sites and communities. He deserved this chance, and I know we'll see great things. Dharman will come back next election cycle with even more experience and hopefully be a shoe-in. Plenty more things to delete in the mean-time.

Comment: @mickmackusa no, it was a thumbs up to Undo.  What made you think otherwise?

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Dharman's original proclamation said "**_Vote for me! I will delete everything._**" (open the original version of the post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62781103/revisions#:~:text=Vote%20for%20me!%20I%20will%20delete%20everything.)

Comment: @mickmackusa with Machavity and Makyen being room owners of SOCVR I didn't view that as noteworthy enough to remember specifically when I was voting for a burninate everything slate.

Comment: @Undo No that is actually Waldo. He is just in disguise.

Answer (score 73):

As easily the most cynical person during the questionnaire phase...let me say this much.

I feel confident that you two will do well in this role.  I feel at ease that you two are joining the existing crew of already talented and disciplined community moderators.

I have trust in your judgment and faith that you both will do what is right and what needs to be done, when it needs to be done, and *how* it needs to be done.

Congratulations to you both!

Comment: You should run in next election - than we will simply know that all users matching Ma* are moderators :)

Comment: You mean all the Macs become Big Macs after election?

Comment: It's funny to me how you think you're the most cynical. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: I like taking the crown.  Gives me the sense that I actually had a lawn to shout at these whippersnappers wantin' to be a moderator as opposed to...y'know, *not*. :D

Comment: Your shouting is welcome on my lawn anytime. These days, I mostly just stay on the porch.

Answer (score 40):

Congratulations to you both on winning the election!

I would also like to say, *thank you* for stepping up to become moderators, especially as we are going through a difficult and uncertain time. I’m sure we will all appreciate your work and wish you the best of luck as you move into your new role!

Answer (score 23):

As a relatively recently active member of the community I have observed both of your work in the SOCVR room and I am in good faith that you two will do a lot of positive contribution to the community as a moderator.

Congratulations to you both on winning the election.

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations to both of you. I would just like to give you one suggestion:

> **"Leaders become great, not because of their power, but because of their ability to empower others."**

Always remember this quote from **John C. Maxwell**. The community has huge hopes for you. Hope you empower the people and continue your helping journey on SO. All the best and **Keep Making Magic**.

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations for both of you, Makyen and Machavity.

You will have a lot of work to do and I think you will be very well placed in that role to keep Stack Overflow clean and serious.

Nonetheless, I would like to see to at least taking a view of [how voting on questionnaires can influence the elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351114/674989) for future elections as both of you had the highest ranked questionnaires at [2020 Community Moderator Election - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399106/2020-community-moderator-election-questionnaire).

Comment: Voting on questionnaires surely influences the elections. It's a bit like an additional primary (with nobody dropping out yet).

Comment: @Trilarion It's a big problem no one really realized yet. If It were on political elections, I would be really in fury.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yet it's kinda neccessary. We need to have the questionnaires, but maybe we could disable the voting?

Comment: in 2019, Machavity was the first top voted in the questionnaire, and lost the election. It's also a matter how who posts the answer first. Baum candidated much later and the questionnaire answer had less votes, but he won

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Very true. Also see [Trilarion's excellent breakdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351155/230855) of other elections.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, Machavity stated that himself in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351121/674989) to my post on Meta. But that it in this case was different doesn't mean that it does not happen as I already stated at this answer. Maybe even at the 2019 election there were votes for him because of that. One example at where a candidate with the highest voted questionnaire made the 8th place is relevant but can't really be an argument that there are no influenced voters. ---

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You pointed the later added nominations which are a big argument to the unfair voting transparency. A later coming candidate is high-probably not be able to get the same amount of upvotes. This is also why at TV votings (by f.e. calls) the lines are open from a point where you can call for every candidate (f.e. the start of the show). Making calls available for one candidate after another would be unfair, because the later ones have a disadvantage in lost time where peole could have vote for them. Fair is to make all lines open at the same time, so no candidate has issues.

Comment: @10Rep No, I doesn't meant to delete doing questionnaires. :-) I love this feature and read me through. It's only about being able to vote on them which is in my humble opinion inappropriate.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yea, thats what I said. Let's disable the voting.