# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderators, announcement

[Moderator election #13](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13) on Stack Overflow has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Stephen Rauch]          [image: Zoe]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! Thanks so much to the other candidates for volunteering.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5141741653983232).

Comment: I do hope Stephen will present himself on meta more than once this year.

Comment: In a complete departure from previous elections, I don't see the same outpour of love for these "new moderators" as we did in previous years. Where are the "congratulations" comments with hundreds of upvotes? Am I the only one totally unsatisfied?

Comment: Maybe you're looking in the wrong place, @cs95? Try checking the "answers" area, rather than the "comments" area.

Comment: @CodyGray Meaning... you promoted the comments to answers? Do people feel an unusual loss for words seeing the election results? Or perhaps were there comments removed? Genuinely asking as I cannot see if any of these things happened as a normal user. ;-)

Comment: No, no comments have been "promoted". That is not possible. What I'm saying is, it seems this year, people are doing what they're supposed to and posting answers, instead of posting comments. There have been no comments removed by moderators so far. @cs95

Comment: I appreciate the candor! Ever the diplomat, but I think you see where I'm coming from seeing as you were also dangerously close to clicking "clear all selections" yourself at one point.

Comment: From the "summary report online", Numbers of Votes + Thresholds don't need 6 Digits after the Dot (=> "xxxx.000000") while these are (or should be) Integers... :idea: https://www.opavote.com/results/5141741653983232

Comment: @chivracq we don't control OpaVote. Their presentation and UI is their own. Many elections end with fractional vote allocations due to Meek STV's methods. Some elections have even ended with extremely small margins.

Comment: @Catija, yep I know you "don't control OpaVote", but that Software/Interface still feels Buggy to me, a "Number of Votes" can only be an integer, you cannot cast a 0.5 or 0.3 Vote...

Comment: @chivracq you are correct that you can't cast a fractional vote... but you can get one. When surplus votes are awarded, it's done proportionally to the second choice votes of all people who participated in reaching the threshold so, in an election your single vote may be split between several candidates. The total votes received is not always an integer.

Comment: @cs95 I agree with you - well said - what's the point of saying "congratulations" if you will get downvoted for saying something good wishing someone the best of luck in this new journey of becoming a mod. Look at a classic example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412572/13669048) how people will disregard your wish by downvoting you. You will not get downvoted unless you are MOD or someone known here on from what I can see.

Comment: Interresting how one "congratulation" answer is at +32 and another is at -4.

Comment: @4386427 Very interesting but guess what nothing would be done about that.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Why should something be "done"? What *could* even be "done"? Users are allowed to vote on posts, up or down, for whatever reason they like. That reason might even be that one of the posts included a giant picture of garbage! Why that's worth an upvote is anyone's guess.

Comment: I see where you're coming from but that isn't wasn't exactly my point, @AlwaysHelping If you look at past election result threads for example [2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399609)  and [2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381524) there's a clear difference in energy levels in the comments ... which becomes obvious if you pay attention. Multiple congratulatory answers have always been frowned upon (since subsequent congratulatory posts don't add much (beyond goodwill) over the existing ones and are typically downvoted).

Comment: All the best to the new mods and thanks to all candidates. Looking at the past elections there seems to be a trend towards a lower number of candidates and maybe also a lower number of voters (relative to the number of possible voters). The trend might change though in the future. This election maybe also showed that reputation or candidate score are weighted higher by voters than answering the optional questionnaire. Maybe the rationale of voters is that if something is optional, it cannot be that important. If it's changed it might be scraped completely or even made mandatory.

Comment: @cs95 You have to scale the number of upvotes on comments by the number of views. The thread from 2020 was seen 11k times so far, this here 10 times lower so far, one would expect ten times lower scores then.

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators, Zoe and Stephen Rauch! ...

Comment: @Trilarion I expect the primary reason candidate score is such a strong predictor of voting is that most voters don't spend a lot of time evaluating the candidates. A large number of voters *probably* spend very little time and likely look primarily, or even almost only, at the candidate score. The percentage of users which take the time to read all, or most, of the questionnaires is probably quite low. While higher, the number that read even most candidate statements is probably not high. A large percentage of people will use the easiest way to evaluate candidates: the candidate score.

Comment: @Makyen I agree. The candidate score is also a measure of participation, although maybe not the best one. If voters go for participation and trust most or want to reward those that have participated the most, that's fine with me.

Comment: @Trilarion I think it's not about the rep or score, but rather the result of already being a mod somewhere and having an impressive achievements by the time of 2018's election (if you took a look at it).

Comment: @Makyen And that leads us to conclusion that in order to improve a relevance of results it should be improved to represent a solid measure or be removed completely. On the other hand I'm largely satisfied with an election _process_ on SE, I wish elections IRL would be _that_ transparent and backed up with numbers...

Comment: @Makyen for me it's quite the opposite. I read the entirety of the candidature posts, and liked Stephen's post because it showed some "I don't need to jump through your hoops, I know what i'm worth" confidence, in addition to being a mod already

Comment: I dont think who is a moderator makes any difference. the SO policies that they are going to enforce arent healthy anymore. the SO 5yrs ago was different and I think it was a lot more friendly and useful. Now idk what it is anymore.

Comment: Congrats to the winners. This is not an easy job and you have volunteered to take on a thankless job. We appreciate your commitment and dedication. I look forward to supporting and doing my part and helping SO users have the best experience. During COVID, I wanted to get answer for a simple question and I stayed on to learn so much. This is a great community and mods like you make it special. Thank You and Congrats again.

Comment: Congratulations to the new Shovel Knights! And to Dharman... you just missed it by the looks of it. Better luck next time.

Comment: @Zoe I got surprised. You never stopped trying and finally, you got it. Congrats!

Answer (score 178):

Congratulations to the new moderators, Zoe and Stephen Rauch!

We saved some flags for you in the queue:

[image: large and degraded garbage pile]

<sup>([Stock photo, copyright
nnonthamand, from 123rf.com](https://www.123rf.com/photo_114526681_mountain-garbage-large-and-degraded-garbage-pile-pile-of-stink-and-toxic-residue-waste-plastic-bottl.html))</sup>

So enough celebrating; now get to work!

Comment: Thanks, would be boring if there was nothing to do after the election :p

Comment: Can't speak for stack overflow, but my experiences moderating other sites has shown that if you do the job right, it [rarely lives up to expectations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg14jNbBb-8).

Comment: Yeah, if you run for SO moderator because you want "power", you're going to be very disappointed. If you do it because you like wielding a giant shovel, then you'll probably be quite satisfied.

Comment: Giant shovel trumps the usual hand trowel.

Comment: Not to be confused with [a towel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaiX680XWP4&t=2m14s).

Comment: Whoa, are those even flags? Those look like T-shirts.

Comment: It's not a real photo of the flag queue, no. We can't show that, because moderator flags are confidential. @Someone_who_likes_SE

Comment: Queue is really such messy ? Cant imagine, good luck !

Comment: I think it **is** a real photo. I see my four pending flags back there, on the right.

Comment: Come on folks those aren't our flags... it's the flagged content

Comment: "So enough celebrating; now get to work!" - is this paid for?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald Puh-lease. Stack Overflow's not about something as crass as money.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald No, moderator is an entirely volunteer position. There is no compensation whatsoever, monetary or otherwise. (Aside from the good feelings one gets in helping to keep the site they care about clean.)

Comment: Congratulations - Will try best not to bore you.

Comment: @CodyGray I've heard of some SWAG being involved... ;-)

Answer (score 123):

Congratulations to both Zoe and Stephen Rauch! Welcome to the team!

Thank you to all the candidates for volunteering for what is a substantial amount of work and an often thankless job.

Comment: `a substantial amount of work and an often thankless job.` I'm not blaming anyone but I see this sentiment across many sites. With such enthusiasm about the role of a moderator on SO, it's no wonder there were only five candidates. Users who already *knew* what the job was like. This air of pessimism is a byproduct of the company's lack of attention and users' indifference toward its volunteers. By lack of attention, I also refer to the lack of perks. There must be personal satisfaction, joy, and recognition when undertaking any role. A volunteer must be valued and *always* listened to.

Comment: See also this [tongue-in-cheek response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412570/3618829) posted by Cody Gray. Hardly a thrilling way to start the day.

Comment: `often thankless job` I blame SO policy of avoiding `Thanks!` in comments.

Comment: Thanks for doing a outstanding job of moderation! I like your stable attitude :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou Stack Overflow moderation occurs at an *entirely* different scale from other Stack Exchange sites. It has nothing to do with feeling unsupported by staff, or the job lacking "perks" (not that I know what such perks would be, other than getting a better, cleaner site). SO mods remind people of the extreme standard of duty that is required for moderating this site in order to ensure that people from other SE sites don't misjudge what type of commitment is really required here. We most definitely only want candidates who already know what the job is like. Nothing else is sustainable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Posting a picture of garbage to welcome new moderators is a tradition (kind of) on SO. People have been doing it for years. See [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338289/november-2016-community-moderator-election-results), [2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354232/2017-community-moderator-election-results), [2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381524/2019-community-moderator-election-results)

Comment: @CodyGray I'm aware of the site's credo and the sheer volume of bad or poorly formulated posts that are generated daily (despite my conspicuous non-participation). And I appreciate the dedication and stamina that many of SO's moderators possess, but it seems the number of passionate, and active moderators on SO is dwindling as it's also apparent on other SE sites I frequent, the exception being Meta where... never mind. I was disappointed that Robert Harvey did not nominate themself but I can understand why. And that is part of what "support" and "recognition" means to me.

Comment: As for "perks" that was an ill choice of expression because if it were true then those perks would generate only resentment and jealousy among many users, but I was thinking along the lines of gratification from TPTB. And the assurance that immunity is guaranteed when criticism is voiced by one or more of its volunteers. Are *you* free to express dissidence in private? I don't know, I would hope that to be the case.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica Looks like one more thing we missed out on in 2020 thanks to COVID...

Comment: You can thank the mods by performing every day moderation activities, like editing, closing, reopening, voting, etc. Clearly  mods enjoy flags, so give them more

Answer (score 69):

Congrats to the new moderators. I'm sure you'll do well and bring balance to the force :)

I think we need to recognize this year there wasn't a lot of interest and in future years there's something wrong if we continue to skip primaries. This year, I get it, the company has new owners and some still have reservations about what's happened in the past.

Therefore, for this reason we need to give a BIG SHOUT out to @Dharman and @RyanM who, despite one nominating themselves multiple times unsuccessfully, continue to put in tireless effort. Sure, they use the spam tooling and while it may not seem like much... when was the last time you saw spam on SO?

Again, congrats to the moderators, and **appreciation to the unsung heroes who uphold the site's health**!

Comment: Nitpick: This was Ryan's first time nominating himself for moderator on Stack Overflow. But, yes, a huge shout-out to the losers of the election, too! We appreciate your standing in the election, and we hope you'll run again in the future. And, of course, we can always use your help throughout the year, doing all the things that do not require moderator privileges (there are many, many more of such things than there are things that require a diamond).

Comment: I thought about that. Fixed.

Comment: @CodyGray Looking at the photo you posted above, one should wonder, "Who is the real loser?"

Answer (score 58):

I do hope Stephen will present himself on meta more than once this year.

Comment: Does this count?

Comment: @StephenRauch no :-)

Comment: Maybe these count: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)?

Comment: @AdrianMole Wow, that's impressive! I can hardly find any posts that need review on meta. I guess now I know the reason :-D

Comment: From all the 20 moderators many aren't very active on meta, so I would not ask more from Stephen than we ask from all of them. As long as at least some moderators are active and speak for all the moderators (i.e. internally communicate with each other) it should be fine.

Comment: Maybe Zoe and Stephen will complement each-other out, one spending *too much* time on meta, and the other not spending enough.

Answer (score 55):

Gutsy play to submit this literally at the last minute and not answer the questionnaire (even though you don't *have* to) and to have a large amount of votes.  Congrats, Stephen!  Hopefully you feel less like a stranger in these parts and you will prove to be a valuable moderator.

Zoe, congrats as well!  In light of what's happened and how you've been involved in the site, I feel at least reasonably confident that you'll be able to handle this role just fine.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, they are much appreciated.

Comment: @StephenRauch What a clean play!! Congrats!

Comment: lol. in hockey, "clean play" is codename for "absolutely brutal check in the boards that should really be a foul but old traditions that have costed countless injuries are long in dying away". Evidently this is not a metaphor about the nomination, checking in hockey is nothing like moderation on SO :)

Answer (score 46):

Congratulations to Zoe and Stephen Rauch!  (Better you than me!)

Zoe, I applaud your bravery in being the first to nominate, and your transparency in your statement.  I've seen your work often and wish you the best.  I've already seen hints in various places that you're settling in well with your new giant shovel.

Stephen Rauch, I applaud your last-minute entry to make the election interesting!  While I haven't seen much of you it's because you've already been working hard behind the scenes, and I have no doubt you'll continue the great work you've already been doing.

Comment: Definitely throw your hat in the ring next time Daniel!

Answer (score 18):

Well it was my first SO election and it's nice to see many candidates apply for like it is said on different places "an often thankless job".
So congratulations to the winner and good luck for the job ! And best of luck to the other candidates for a future election :)

Comment: I got a "thank you" once. Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: Should we believe that, then? ^ :D

Comment: "once" %) in how long ? ;)

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations to the new moderators! We look forward for a bright future... All the  candidates who applied for moderator election are invaluable resources to SO... Good Luck and keep learning!

Answer (score 7):

Congrats to Zoe and Stephen Rauch!

Best wishes to both of you, moderators!

Answer (score -3):

Congratulations to the new moderators, Zoe and Stephen Rauch! best of wishes to you guys! I hope you guys play a great role in Stack Overflow and help to grow more and more :)

Answer (score -8):

Congratulations Mr. Rauch. It doesn't come as a surprise a perfect candidate with a perfect 40/40 score has won, it was only logical.

Comment: That is, assuming that the score actually measures something useful. How confident are you that it does? Meaningless metrics are pretty common these days. Did you do any research to find out what it actually means and then decide for yourself whether that has any relevance to what you want to see in a moderator?

Comment: @CodyGray `That is, assuming that the score actually measures something useful. How confident are you that it does?` the usefulness of the measure doesn't matter, what matters is how many people use the metric for their voting. I stand by what I said in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412343/is-it-gaming-the-system-when-a-moderator-candidate-submits-their-nomination-at-t/412358#412358 and I strongly believe, that them being the only candidate with a 40/40 score gave them a huge boost, that ultimately resulted in a win

Comment: No, I don't think that measure is useful. I don't even think general voting is useful. I have zero confidence for average person doing voting to be "fully informed"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I failed to make the connection to you being the same user who confused me before. You are making a demonstrative argument against the use of the metric altogether. Well, I suppose I can agree with that. The outcome of the election certainly has strengthened your case, even though it hasn't made your arguments any clearer.

Comment: Who knows what goes on in the mind of a voter? To pretend otherwise is disingenuous.

Comment: If only the same voters came to meta and saw this.. ;)

Comment: Phew, what a philosophycal question: *is any vote sensible as some voters could not have clearly understood the real implication of their vote, what the candidate really are nor what they will really do*. Well of course Trump was once elected... I would just cite Churchill *Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all the others.*

Comment: @SergeBallesta democracy is necessary in "real life" politics, because the candidates emphasize and promise different things, take different stances compared to others. Voters vote for the direction the nation should go, not just for the candidate's fitness to implement that direction. But that's not quite what is happening when it comes site moderation, is it? All candidates promise the same thing in different words, the question is literally just about their fitness. I see no upside of general vote compared to, say, existing mods simply doing an internal vote on the given candidates

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I do not believe that to be true. You can vote for a candidate that is more prone to suspending users than talking to them first. Or one that is less likely to delete unpopular meta posts. Or one that closes and deletes posts instead of editing them. So your vote very much is a vote to the direction you want the site to go in.

Comment: Sarcasm and the Internet are a poor mix. I relearn this lesson almost daily.

Comment: Your answers tend to attract a lot of downvotes, seemingly because they're misunderstood (?) - The weird part is I understood your point in both answers very clearly (I didn't even know you're the same person who posted the other answer) but at the same time, I can see how they could be misunderstood. Maybe it's the way you write your answers with a sarcastic tone and how brief they are? Maybe you actually _intend_ to have a little bit of ambiguity in them? :-D Anyway, I second what you said here.

Comment: _Correlation != Causation_. With a sample size of __one__, attributing his election ___solely___ to his 40/40 score is a stretch, and even a little insulting to those that got elected.

Comment: I am sure the score helped but the “gaming” accusation may have helped too since it gave Stephen an opportunity to point out that they did answer last year’s questionnaire. (At least I didn’t know you could still get to those answers before that happened.)